# Windows App Certification Kit - An error occurred while generating the report

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

While creating app package for Windows Phone Store following error is displayed. 

 Tried Reboot, Re-installing SDK, Re-installing VS Tools, Run as administrator. 

 None of them seems to make a difference.

[image: screenshot]

Following is the log from: logotest_trace file in %AppData%/.../AppCertKit folder

`appcertui.exe Information: 0 : Timestamp INFO:InstalledPrograms Modifying report file %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKit\tempReport.xml.
appcertui.exe Information: 0 : Timestamp EXCEPTION[Infrastructure]: Infrastructure part name: "InstalledPrograms.cs", Method name: "ExecuteCreateReportTask_Tailored" Line: 227,
     Comment: N/A
     Exception message: Cannot import a null node.
     Exception trace:    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ImportNodeInternal(XmlNode node, Boolean deep)
   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tasks.InstalledPrograms.ExecuteCreateReportTask_Tailored(TaskData taskData)
appcertui.exe Information: 0 : Timestamp INFO:DependencyInformation Inserting information from %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKit\aitoutputToUpload_776ba89a-41b0-4ead-8978-47dd9eff5b6c.xml.`

Comment: Have you tried testing with some build in apps like Groove Music? Does it have the same problem? Besides have you tried with [10.01.14393.033](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=822845) SDK?

Comment: No I haven't tested it with Groove Music and older SDK versions. I just installed SDK first from visual studio and later from standalone installation.  Both result in same error. I'll check with Groove Music if possible soon :)

Comment: someone has a solution for this issue?

Comment: @smedasn: Never figured out how to fix this issue, but, it doesn't stop anyone from uploading new app builds. Uploaded builds seem to pass the Microsoft App Certification Step/Process just fine.  
--- P.S. We moved to windows 10 and we no longer see the error.

Comment: @codermd thank you for the response. Unfortunately I have a windows desktop application. looks like i have to purchase a certificate.

Comment: Seeing this in VS 2017 UWP app, latest updates. One app validates another does not. Both run fine. The one that does not validate, the validator does not even launch during validation.